# No setter/field for ( ) found on my class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to make a login screen for my application, but when I enter the right Id and password that should work my application keeps stopping. Furthermore, When I debug the codes, error messages such as:

```
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for User found on class com.example.(Projectname).User
 No setter/field for BookReport found on class com.example.(Projectname).User

 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.(Projectname), PID: 3339
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.(Projectname).LoginScreen$1$1.onDataChange(LoginScreen.java:79)
```

Comes out. Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you show the code for your `User` class?

Comment: Obviously `userId` or `userPw` is null, whichever line 79 is. Which part of the error message confuses you? Perhaps if you add null check, e.g. `if (userId != null && userId.equals(id))`, the code wouldn't fail.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/5221149)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I added it in my original post

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I think that was the problem thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `com.example.hellobook.User` class does not define setters for its fields. Try defining a setter for all the fields so the statement `foundUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);` can create a correct `User` object

e.g.

```
public void setBookReport(BookReport bookReport){
    this.bookReport = bookReport;
}
```

Comment: Well, nothing can be said, unless the OP posts the `User` class.

Answer (score -1):

sir your error is this line `if (userId.equals(id))`
becuase you set the value of dataSnapShot in foundUser Object outside the for loop.

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            foundUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            userId = foundUser.getId();
                            userPw = foundUser.getPw();
                            if (userId.equals(id)) {
                                if (userPw.equals(psw)) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, LandingScreen.class));
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Wrong ID or password. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError error) {
                        @NonNull DatabaseError databaseError;                        }
                });
            };
```

Comment: Your answer sounded very reasonable and I tried it, but still I cannot solve the problem :((

Comment: does it shows the same error. do you check the log value of user id or debug it. is it null or not before the if check